# How to create draggable pin in windows 10 to give pick location functionality?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am working on MapControl in Windows 10 and I want to allow the user to drag the pin and when the user drops the pin want to get latitude and longitude of that position and get the location address by using API.I added Map Icon using following code

```
MapControl map = frameworkElement as MapControl;
map.MapServiceToken= "my service token";
BasicGeoposition councilPosition = new BasicGeoposition()
{
     Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(Info.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LATITUDE").GetValue(councilInfo, null)),
     Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(Info.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LONGITUDE").GetValue(councilInfo, null))
};

Geopoint pinPoint = new Geopoint(councilPosition);

MapIcon locationPin = new MapIcon();
locationPin.Image= RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/pushpin.png"));
locationPin.Title = councilInfo.COUNCIL_NAME;
locationPin.CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible;
locationPin.Location = councilPoint;
locationPin.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
locationPin.ZIndex = 0;

map.MapElements.Add(locationPin);
await map.TrySetViewAsync(locationPin.Location, 15D, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
```

Can someone suggest which events are required to be used to achieve pick location functionality?

Comment: Let me give an idea. Refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219696.aspx. They have specified display points using XAML. Instead of border you can have Grid with background pushpin image,listen to manipulation events for that grid.. Does it help with your requirement?

Comment: is it not possible with MapIcon? I want to allow user to drag the MapIcon and drop it at other location and when user drops get the location using latitude and latitude.

Comment: I guess not. Because mapicon doesn't have drag events or manipulation events to register. But i haven't worked on that

Comment: ok, Actually I have also not worked on Manipulation events in past so not sure how to use them for drag and drop. Can you add an answer with the sample? If it will meet my requirement will mark the answer as yes and reward bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [link](http://%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219696.aspx). They have specified display points using XAML. Instead of border you can have Grid with background pushpin image,listen to manipulation events for that grid.

here is the code to achieve what i told above.

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BasicGeoposition snPosition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.7356039173901, Longitude = -122.310697222129

            };
            Geopoint snPoint = new Geopoint(snPosition);

            // Create a XAML border.
            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                Width=100,
                Height=100,
                Background = new ImageBrush() {ImageSource= new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)), Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill}
            };
              grid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX|ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
 grid.ManipulationCompleted += Grid_ManipulationCompleted;
            grid.ManipulationDelta +=Grid_ManipulationDelta;
            // Center the map over the POI.
            MapControl1.Center = snPoint;
            MapControl1.ZoomLevel = 14;
            CompositeTransform tran = new CompositeTransform();
            grid.RenderTransform = tran;
            // Add XAML to the map.
            MapControl1.Children.Add(grid);
            MapControl.SetLocation(grid, snPoint);
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(grid, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
        }  

        private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid grid = sender as Grid;
            CompositeTransform xform = grid.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;


            xform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            xform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
         //   Rect point = grid.TransformToVisual(MapControl1).TransformBounds(new Rect(0,0, grid.Width, grid.Height));

            e.Handled = true;
          //  Geopoint gPoint;
           // MapControl1.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(point.X, point.Y), out gPoint);
           // Debug.WriteLine(gPoint.Position.Latitude);
           // Debug.WriteLine(gPoint.Position.Longitude);
        }

  private void Grid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid grid = sender as Grid;
            Rect point = grid.TransformToVisual(MapControl1).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, grid.Width, grid.Height);
            Geopoint gPoint;
            MapControl1.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(point.X, point.Y), out gPoint);
            Debug.WriteLine(gPoint.Position.Latitude);
            Debug.WriteLine(gPoint.Position.Longitude);
        }
```

Location fetched after drag is not that accurate. You can do bit R&D on how to fetch accuarate point wrt to `MapControl`

Comment: Thanks will give it a try.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if there is any problems

Comment: The event was called many times. It display many locations. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. What you want is to gett location when drag is completed right? I ll update the answer

Comment: yes and that icon is the image, will it point to perfect co-ordinates inside a grid also? If I add image as child of Grid then will it work?

Comment: I updated the answer. I dint get last query. That image is not proper. I just used as placeholder. You have to givecorrect image without that white spaces on each side

Comment: why do you want to add image as child? i guess both has same effect

Comment: yes it will run when Manipulation is completed. You have to find correct Offset(correct point wrt to MapControl). I tried TransformToVisual() method. I thing it gives top-left corner points. You have to find point where icon tip resides. hope its making sense. If you find that point you can use TransformPoint(point) instead of TransformBounds() method

Comment: Because it's not pointing to proper co-ordinates. Also, I tried your updated code but still the events is called many times. If we comment `grid.ManipulationDelta +=Grid_ManipulationDelta` then will it work?

Comment: Yes Grid_ManipulationDelta  will be called many times. I'm using to move the grid,as you can see i'm adding TranslateX and TranslateY. What i said is use ManipulationCompleted  event to show the updated location. Remove it from Grid_ManipulationDelta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110484/discussion-between-kinjan-bhavsar-and-lovetocode).

Comment: no. i dint remove. I sent the screenshoots in discussion

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the accepted answer to work. After a lot of research and help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480276/creating-a-draggable-map-pin-on-uwp#42510015), I finally got it working. Here's a working sample:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
            {
                Latitude = 30.3618,
                Longitude = -91.1067
            });
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                Width = 32,
                Height = 50
            };
            var pushpin = new Image()
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Pushpin.png")),
                Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
                ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY,
                RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform()
            };
            pushpin.ManipulationStarted += Pushpin_ManipulationStarted;
            pushpin.ManipulationDelta += Pushpin_ManipulationDelta;
            pushpin.ManipulationCompleted += Pushpin_ManipulationCompleted;
            grid.Children.Add(pushpin);

            Map.Center = position;
            Map.Children.Add(grid);
            MapControl.SetLocation(grid, position);
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(grid, new Point(0.5, 1));
        }

        private Geopoint GetPosition(Image pushpin)
        {
            var grid = pushpin.Parent as Grid;
            var anchor = MapControl.GetNormalizedAnchorPoint(grid);
            var offset = pushpin.TransformToVisual(Map).TransformPoint(new Point(grid.Width * anchor.X, grid.Height * anchor.Y));
            Map.GetLocationFromOffset(offset, out Geopoint position);
            return position;
        }

        private void Pushpin_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Map.PanInteractionMode = MapPanInteractionMode.Auto;

            var pushpin = sender as Image;
            var grid = pushpin.Parent as Grid;
            var position = GetPosition(pushpin);
            MapControl.SetLocation(grid, position);
            var transform = pushpin.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            transform.X = 0;
            transform.Y = 0;
        }

        private void Pushpin_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pushpin = sender as Image;
            var transform = pushpin.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            transform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            transform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }

        private void Pushpin_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Map.PanInteractionMode = MapPanInteractionMode.Disabled;
        }
    }
```